# Целесообразность создания экземпляров Point при задании позиции

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Здравствуйте! Данный вопрос касательно оптимальности.

Каким способом из двух, при программном создании элемента управления в WinForms, лучше задавать координаты?

1) `element.Location = new Point(x, y);`
2) `element.Location.X = x; element.Location.Y = y;`

Целесообразно ли инициализировать экземпляр `Point` (хотя занимает меньше места и выглядит красивее)?

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите другой ответ, мой ответ оказался ошибочным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2) element.Location.X = x; element.Location.Y = y;

Этот вариант не рабочий. В `Location` можно записать `Point` целиком, а доступ к `Location.X` и `Location.Y` только для чтения, т.к. `Location` свойство а не переменная или поле, о чем студия предупреждает еще до компиляции.

Причина довольно простая - структуры в .NET относятся к типам значениям (value types), следовательно свойство при обращении к нему предоставляет копию значения `Point` и вносить в нее изменения не имеет ни какого смысла.

Comment: Вот как раз статья на связанную тему: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/

Comment: Перепутал X и Y с Top и Left. Действительно, компилятор предупреждает.

Answer (score 0):

Если исходить из красоты, то создание point лучше(раз мы используем объектно ориентированный язык=) При этом в сотнях строчках кода это будет нагляднее и удобнее смотреть.